# check content of zip file then Open and Read it and list content into comboBox using c# WF

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

I want to check content of zip file, if there is a `csv` file. If so I want to list this content into a `comboBox`. That what I try work fine, but no check was done.

```
var = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            fullpath = fbd.SelectedPath + "\\"+ var;

            comboBox2.Items.Clear();
            if (File.Exists(fullpath)) 
            {
                ZipArchive zip = ZipFile.OpenRead(fullpath);
                foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in zip.Entries)
                {
                    comboBox2.Items.Add(entry.FullName); // fill comboBox2 with *.csv files from selected zip file
                }
                zip.Dispose();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no csv files present");
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a check if the file is really CSV before adding it to the combo box.

Use this check:

```
if (entry.Name.EndsWith("csv")
    comboBox2.Items.Add(entry.FullName);
```

Comment: I wanted to program a message that tells me if there is one or more cvs file present in the zip file and gives me the number of files contained in this zip.  i tried this but is not working: MessageBox.Show(Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries(fullpath, "*.csv").ToList<string>().Count + " csv file(s) present"); // get error here

Comment: An unhandled exception of type 'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: The directory name is invalid. Break when this exception type is thrown

Comment: The exception itself clearly specifies the problem. Check if your fullpath is actually a valid path.

Comment: Thanks for your time!!! The fullpath is a valid path. I've solved the problem whithout using Directory.EnumerateFileSystemEntries like this: MessageBox.Show(count + " csv file(s) present"); and its work fine.